# Can I upload attachments to Dropbox from Mail.app?

Tags: macos, dropbox, sparrow

Now that Google has bought Sparrow, and Sparrow for OS X is likely to be gutted soon, I'm contemplating going back to Apple's Mail.app. However, one of the best features I've found in Sparrow is the ability to upload attachments to my Dropbox public folder.

Does anyone know of a way of replicating this functionality in Mail.app, via Applescript or something similar? I'd like to be able to drag files into a message and have them uploaded to Dropbox in the background.

My (future) workaround is to manually move files into my public folder and copy/paste their links, but I'd love to find something faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site http://sendtodropbox.com/
It lets you create a unique email address. 
Then  you can just forward the mail with the attachment you wanna save, and it goes to your dropbox automatically.